# private htmlelement is suddenly undefined

Tags: typescript

I've created a class for some DOM manipulation in Typescript.

```
export class MyClass {
  private outSelector: string;
  private outElem: HTMLElement;

  constructor(outSelector: string) {
    this.outSelector = outSelector;
    this.outElem = document.querySelector(this.outSelector)!;
  }

  init(): void {
    this.outElem.addEventListener('mousedown', this.mouseDown, false);
    this.outElem.addEventListener('mouseup', this.mouseUp, false);
    this.outElem.addEventListener('mousemove', this.mouseMove, false); 
    console.log(this.outElem);
  }

  createRect(): void {
    const newRect = document.createElement('div');
    console.log(this.outElem);
    this.outElem.appendChild(newRect);
  }

  //...
}
```

I'm calling the `createRect()` from another file.

```
const cls = new MYClass('#pv');
const rBtn = document.querySelector("#cr");
rBtn?.addEventListener("click", cls.createRect, false)
```

The outElem member is there when init() is called but its undefined when createRect() is called by the other file. What happens here?

Also, this is my first time writing any typescript so any other suggestions are welcomed.

**Update:** I made it work by converting `createRect()` to an arrow function. But I still have no clue what's going here and why arrow function solved the issue. Should all methods in a class in typescript be arrow functions?

Comment: I quickly tested your snippet and looks fine to me: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-94yn8n?file=index.ts)

Comment: @lbsn really weird, still getting the error on local env

Comment: Can you add the caller code in "the other file"?

Comment: @yume_chan I'm just adding an event listener and passing in the function, check updated code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not related to TypeScript. In JavaScript, `this` in normal `function`s and class methods are determined by how it was called, usually in two ways:

1. In `a.b()`, the `this` value in `b` is `a`. For example if I have the following code:

```js
const definitelyNotYourClass = {
    value: 42,
    fn: cls.createRect,
};

definitelyNotYourClass.fn();
```

Then the `this` in `definitelyNotYourClass.fn` (actually `cls.createRect`) is the `definitelyNotYourClass` object.

2. Use `Function.prototype.call`/`Function.prototype.apply` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)) to specify `this` value.

---

`addEventListener` works similar to scenario 2 above. It saves your event handler into a internal slot, then when the event triggers, it `apply` the event handler with some `this` value, usually the `EventTarget`.

---

Arrow functions ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)), on the other hand, capture their `this` values from the creation scope. And arrow functions in class is a syntax sugar for

```js
class MyClass {
    constructor() {
        this.createRect = () => { /* ... */ };
    }
}
```

When it was created, the `this` value is an instance of `MyClass`, so it saves the instance, and no matter how it was called, always use this value as its `this`.

---

Another common solution is to use `Funciton.prototype.bind` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)), which is like arrow functions, allows capture a `this` value. Usually it's used in constructors:

```
class MyClass {
    constructor() {
        this.createRect = this.createRect.bind(this);
    }

    createRect() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

---

In JavaScript, the `class` keyword is just a syntax sugar for the legacy and confusing prototype definition. It's OK for new JavaScript learners to not dig into all the details of prototype and just remember how to use `class`, but if you want to learn more about why it's designed as this, you can check the [Inheritance and the prototype chain article on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain).

---

**EDIT**:

Arrow functions and `bind` can also be used at caller site, like:

```js
element.addEventListener('click', () => cls.createRect());
// or
element.addEventListener('click', cls.createRect.bind(cls));
```

However, there are two problems with it:

1. Arrow functions and `bind` creates a new function object every time, so they have a small overhead. Use them in class constructor ensure only one function is created for each instance, but if being used at multiple sites, it can cause a (very) small performance and memory issue.
2. You can't use `removeEventListener` to remove the event handler, unless you save the created function elsewhere, which is harder to use.

---

If you know methods of a class may be used without `a.b()` form, it's recommended to use arrow functions or `bind` in class definition, it can simplify things.

Comment: Instead of making the class method an arrow function, I used one in the event handler like `() => cls.createRect()`. This is better right?